# Calling python 2.7 opens python 2.4

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-2.4

I'm a bit of a Linux newbie, and I ssh into a remote Linux server where I have no root access. The system has Python 2.4.3 available and I have Python 2.7.9 installed locally in ~/usr/bin. I tried unsuccessfully to setup a virtual environment using [this](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/virtual-python.py) python script. After I did this, I suddenly couldn't run python 2.7 anymore. Even typing `$ ~/usr/bin/python2.7` runs python 2.4.3. I can't figure out how to reverse this problem. Was some environment variable changed?

Comment: What do you get if you say `which python -a`? Also, you may have symlinked one python to another

Comment: Also what does `ls -l ~/usr/bin/python2.7` say? Maybe a symbolic link to somewhere else?

Comment: @fedorqui `which python -a` outputs `/usr/bin/python` and `~/usr/bin/python`. I assume the first one (which points to 2.4.3) is the one called when I type `python`. How do I change that?

Comment: @ThomasKilian That command outputs `-rwxr-xr-x 1 lindsb rrclustr 8304 Feb  1 16:15 /home/lindsb/usr/bin/python2.7`, but there is a symbolic link going from `python` to `python2.7` in that directory. `ls -l ~/usr/bin/python` outputs `lrwxrwxrwx 1 lindsb rrclustr 9 Feb  1 16:33 /home/lindsb/usr/bin/python -> python2.7`

Comment: @Scarecrow I'm hoping to keep that as a last resort. Also, I'm hoping this will help me understand a little more of what's going on under the hood in linux.

Comment: So if you explicitly open python with the full path you found and it opens the wrong version then it has been overwritten and you must go the un-/install way.

Comment: @ThomasKilian OK, good to know. If you post that as an answer I'll select it and this will be an officially answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the path of the executable using `which` / by resolving symbolic links (via `ls -l`). When you open python with the fond path manually and it prints the wrong path the some installation has overwritten your python. In that case you need to un-/install python.